# Is it possible to make a "wait seconds" function in Android?

Tags: android

I wanna make a function for waiting 2 seconds, and then doing something (display a text).

Is there any way to do that? Thanks

I post the code, and if you can tell me if it is possible...

Code where I wanna put it (it's commented)

```
case (R.id.addPoints1):

    if(restar){

         pp1 = pp1 - 1;
         playerPoints1.setText(Integer.toString(pp1));
         restar = false;

    } else {

         pp1 = pp1 + 1;
         playerPoints1.setText(Integer.toString(pp1));

    }

    if(pp1 == 10){

         String messageString = "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat";
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         Snackbar message = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout), messageString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
         message.show();
         pp1 = 0;

         //WAIT 2 SECONDS
         playerPoints1.setText(Integer.toString(pp1));
     }
     break;

 case (R.id.addPoints2):

     if(restar){

         pp2 = pp2 - 1;
         playerPoints2.setText(Integer.toString(pp2));
         restar = false;

     }else {

         pp2 = pp2 + 1;
         playerPoints2.setText(Integer.toString(pp2));

     }

     if(pp2 == 10){

         String messageString = "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat";
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         Snackbar message = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout), messageString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
         message.show();
         pp2 = 0;

         //WAIT 2 SECONDS
         playerPoints2.setText(Integer.toString(pp2));
     }
     break;

 case (R.id.addPoints3):

     if(restar){

         pp3 = pp3 - 1;
         playerPoints3.setText(Integer.toString(pp3));
         restar = false;

     }else {

         pp3 = pp3 + 1;
          playerPoints3.setText(Integer.toString(pp3));

     }

     if(pp3 == 10){

         String messageString = "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat";
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         Snackbar message = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout), messageString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
         message.show();
         pp3 = 0;

         //WAIT 2 SECONDS
         playerPoints3.setText(Integer.toString(pp3));

     }
     break;

 case (R.id.addPoints4):

     if(restar == true){

          pp4 = pp4 - 1;
          playerPoints4.setText(Integer.toString(pp4));
          restar = false;

     }else {

          pp4 = pp4 + 1;
          playerPoints4.setText(Integer.toString(pp4));

     }

     if(pp4 == 10){

          String messageString = "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat";
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 punts! Agafa la foto de la ciutat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          Snackbar message = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout), messageString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
          message.show();
          pp4 = 0;

          //WAIT 2 SECONDS
          playerPoints4.setText(Integer.toString(pp4));

      }
      break;
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call your function
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: and then, could I call the run() from any part of the activity?

Comment: no.. it is overridden method of runnable.. you can't access it outside of its scope.

Comment: mmmm... i edit the post, and put some code, where I wanna put the timer. Can u plz tell me if it is possible?

Comment: you need to just set your text inside run method, i see you have 3 textview which you want to set text after 2 seconds. you have to write separate Handler for each. use this code every time you set text.

Answer (score 2):

Try `CountDown Timer`:

```
 new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();
```

Comment: Where should I place this?

Comment: @user6463207 In your Activity's onCreate() method.